# Java - How to order capital letters before lowercase letters using CompareTo method

Tags: java

Let's say, for example that I have the **same** 2 strings but the first one starts with
capital letter and the second one isn't.
Now, I need to order capital letters before lowercase letters using CompareTo method.
How do I do that? because CompareTo method will order them the opposite way.

An Example: List = { "world","Aple","World", "aple","Hello"}
the order I want to get is: "Aple","Hello","World", "aple", "world". Meaning, no matter what, uppercase letters come first.

Comment: Implement a custom comparator.

Comment: This is due to ascii values are used for the comparison. A is #65, a is #97. You'll have to write your own comparison method.

Comment: What do you mean by "order capital letters before lowercase letters"?

Comment: Uppercase letters _are_ ordered before lowercase letters, due to having lower character values. `System.out.println("A".compareTo("a"))` will return a negative value. What is it you are looking for?

Comment: All I'm trying to do is to sort strings that starts with capital letters before lowercase letters. for example: A.txt comes before a.txt. Notice that a.txt comes before b.txt.

Comment: You will get better answers -- ones that answer your real question, rather than the answerer's interpretation of you question -- if you (1) give some examples and the way they should be ordered, and (2) show your current code and its output for those examples.

Comment: What you want is the "natural" sort order for a `List<String>`. What happened when you used `Collections.sort()`? If you didn't get the results you expected, please show your code.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
public class StringSorter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("apple");
        list.add("Hello");
        list.add("Apple");
        list.add("World");
        list.add("hello");

        Collections.sort(list,
                new Comparator<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                        if(o1.equalsIgnoreCase(o2)){
                            return o1.compareTo(o2);
                        }
                        return o1.toUpperCase().compareTo(o2.toUpperCase());
                    }

                });

        System.out.println(list);

        // in a shorter way with java-8
        list.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::toLowerCase));
    }

}
```

Comment: can you explain why is it working? why did you had to turn all the letters in o1,02 to capital letters and compare between them?

Comment: If you sort in natural order the upper case get precedence. So partly this will satisfy your requirement because "Apple" comes before "apple". But then any lower-case letter will come after upper-case ones. Say "Apple" comes before "hello". This is wrong. So first we need a case-insensitive sorting. That is why that `toUpperCase`. However if both are same then we could just sort it via the default compare Java gives. So first if check for case-insensitive equality and sort in default method.

Comment: So maby I'll explain my qustion a little bit more: according to your example, the order I want to get is: "Aple","Hello","World", "aple", "world". Meaning, no matter what, uppercase letters come first.

Comment: That is very simple.. You don't need any customization. Java gives it out of the box. Just use `Collections.sort(list);`. No comparator.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `compareTo` method or implement the [`Comparable` Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

The documentation says that the return value for this is

> -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive.

So, you only need to do your own string comparisons and return the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a(the) standard implementation of string comparisons:

```
public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
    int len1 = value.length;
    int len2 = anotherString.value.length;
    int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
    char v1[] = value;
    char v2[] = anotherString.value;

    int k = 0;
    while (k < lim) {
        char c1 = v1[k];
        char c2 = v2[k];
        if (c1 != c2) {
            return c1 - c2;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return len1 - len2;
}
```

You'll need to write a method like this that changes the char values, e.g. swapping uppercase and lowercase.  Then as netinept says, use it in a sort algorithm as a 'compareTo' override or 'Comparable' implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work - I am tinkering with the returns so it may change.

```
static class CasedStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if ( o1 == null ) {
            return -1;
        }
        if ( o2 == null ) {
            return 1;
        }
        for ( int i = 0; i < Math.min(o1.length(), o2.length()); i++ ) {
            char c1 = o1.charAt(i);
            char c2 = o2.charAt(i);
            if ( Character.isUpperCase(c1) && !Character.isUpperCase(c2)) {
                return -1;
            }
            if ( !Character.isUpperCase(c1) && Character.isUpperCase(c2)) {
                return 1;
            }
            int diff = Character.compare(c1, c2);
            if (diff != 0) {
                return diff;
            }
        }
        if ( o1.length() < o2.length() ) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But as @GriffeyDog points out - this does not change the default ordering which also puts uppercase before lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I liked Syam S answer. And thought of trying in different way.
I believe it is comparatively efficient too

Off course - add null check :)

```
Collections.sort(list,
            new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int min = Math.min(o1.length(), o2.length());
            for (int k = 0; k < min ; k++ ){
                char c1 = o1.charAt(k);
                char c2 = o2.charAt(k);
                if (c1 != c2 ){
                    char u1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
                    char u2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
                    if (u1 == u2) {
                        return Character.isUpperCase(c1) ? -1 : 1;
                    }else{
                        return u1 - u2;
                    }
                }
            }

            return o1.length() - o2.length();
        }

    });
```