# Custom Sorting in way that A comes before a and B comes before b

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of colors like this:

> Pink, Blue, Red, blue, Grey, green, purple, black ...etc

```
List<String> listOfColors =  Arrays.asList("Pink", "Blue", "Red", "blue", "Grey", "green", "purple", "black");
```

There are some intermediate operation like filtering some fruit colors, now I am left with filtered results where I want them to be sorted in order:

> Blue, black, blue, Grey, green, Pink, purple, Red

I have tried :

```java
List<String> collect = listOfColors.stream().sorted(String::compareToIgnoreCase)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It does not work as expected.

The output is the following:

> black, Blue, blue, green, Grey, Pink, purple, Red

I want the following:

> Blue, black, blue, Grey, green, Pink, purple, Red

Comment: Shouldn't black come before blue and green before Grey?

Comment: `a` is before `u` so the result is correct

Comment: @RavindraRanwala , **Blue**'s *B* is capital but **back**'s *b* is not.

Comment: Sounding like you want a kind of double sort.

Comment: @ScaryWombat , i dont know if it it requires double sort, i first thought it will be easy, but after sometime i was seriously confused.

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956618/java-how-to-order-capital-letters-before-lowercase-letters-using-compareto-met

Comment: As a side note, there's already `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` for the specific case in your code.

Comment: I tried, but it does not give this specific order. It gives `[black, Blue, blue, green, Grey, Pink, purple, Red]` @chrylis-onstrike-

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I meant specifically for `compareToIgnoreCase`.

Comment: If you want capital casing to come before lower casing, then ignoring casing is the last thing that you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution is to use sorting in two steps by using the `Comparator.thenComparing()` method.

First, compare the Strings only by the first character ignoring case.
So the groups with the same first character (no matter what case) remain unsorted so far. Then in the second step apply the normal alphabetical sorting to sort those unsorted subgroups.

```
List<String> listOfColors =  Arrays.asList("Pink", "Blue", "Red", "blue", "Grey", "green", "purple", "black");
Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing(s -> 
        Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(0)));
listOfColors.sort(comparator.thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
System.out.println(listOfColors);
```

Maybe it can be still optimized, but it gives the desired result:

> `[Blue, black, blue, Grey, green, Pink, purple, Red]`

Comment: Made an edit for the readability of `Comparator`. But yes, this assumes only comparing the *first character* of the String about which the OP has not emphasized much either.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [RuleBasedCollator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html) to define your own Rules.

Example of **custom** rule:

> ```
> String rules = "< c,C < b,B";
> ```
>
> The above rule is decoded as that both uppercase and lowercase `C`'s
>   are to appear before both uppercase and lowercase `B`'s when comparing
>   strings.

```
String customRules = "<A<a<B<b<C<c<D<d<E<e<F<f<G<g<H<h<I<i<J<j<K<k<L<l<M<m<N<n<O<o<P<p<Q<q<R<r<S<s<T<t<U<u<V<v<X<x<Y<y<Z<z";
RuleBasedCollator myRuleBasedCollator = new RuleBasedCollator(customRules);
Collections.sort(listOfColors,myRuleBasedCollator);
System.out.println(listOfColors);
```

**Output:**

```
[Blue, black, blue, Grey, green, Pink, purple, Red]
```

---

**Edit:** Instead of writing the `customRules` by hand, you can use the below to code to generate it.

```
String a = IntStream.range('a', 'z' + 1).mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char) c))
        .flatMap(ch -> Stream
            .of("<", ch.toUpperCase(), "<", ch)).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

Comment: creation `String customRules` can be automatism with `IntStream`: `IntStream.range('a', 'z' + 1)
                .mapToObj(Character::toString)
                .flatMap(ch -> Stream.of("<", ch.toUpperCase(), "<", ch))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(""))`

Comment: @lczapski , somehow `.mapToObj(Character::toString)` will not get resolved, i guess you need to use `.mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char) c))`

Comment: `mapToObj(Character::toString)` only works in Java 11 or newer.

Comment: @Holger Ok, I tried on my System(JDK-8) and `mapToObj(Character::toString)` was not getting resolved, but i liked the idea so i end up doing casting like `.mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char) c))`

Comment: I’d prefer `IntStream.rangeClosed('a', 'z').flatMap(c -> IntStream.of(c,Character.toUpperCase(c))) .mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char)c)) .collect(Collectors.joining("<", "<", ""));`

Comment: @Holger your version is nicer but the order should be `.flatMap(c -> IntStream.of( Character.toUpperCase(c), c))`

Answer (score 0):

You need a method that first does a case insensitive comparison on each letter, then if there's a match perform a case sensitive comparison on each letter:

```
public static int compare(String s1, String s2)
{
    int len, i;
    if (s1.length()<s2.length()) {
        len = s1.length();
    } else {
        len = s2.length();
    }
    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        if (Character.toUpperCase(s1.charAt(i)) < Character.toUpperCase(s2.charAt(i))) {
            return -1;
        } else if (Character.toUpperCase(s1.charAt(i)) > Character.toUpperCase(s2.charAt(i))) {
            return 1;
        } else if (s1.charAt(i) < s2.charAt(i)) {
            return -1;
        } else if (s1.charAt(i) > s2.charAt(i)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (s1.length() < s2.length()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You can then pass this method to `Stream.sorted`.